# how to disable previous date in calendar extender in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to disallow the previous dates in calendar extender. I'm able to show pop up when previous date is selected, but textbox is not clearing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkDate(sender, args) {
        if (sender._selectedDate < new Date()) {
            alert("You cannot select a day earlier than today!");
            sender._selectedDate = new Date();
            sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
            document.getElementById("txtNextFollowupDate").value = "";//want to make empty
       }
    }
</script>

<tr>
    <td><asp:Label ID="Label18" Text="Next Follow up date" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNextFollowupDate" />
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarNextFollowUpDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtNextFollowupDate" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="checkDate" > </asp:CalendarExtender>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you need to get the Textbox value using `document.getElementById("<%=txtNextFollowupDate.ClientID %>").value=" ";`

Comment: please mark this as answer for other future users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to Clear the Textbox value using :

```
document.getElementById("<%=txtNextFollowupDate.ClientID %>").value=" ";
```